# Connecting to Postgresql docker container using python failing due to credentials error

Tags: python-3.x, docker, sqlalchemy

Connecting to Postgresql docker container using python failing due to credentials error.
connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"

I used this command to run postgresql container

```
docker run -it -e POSTGRES_USER=“username” -e POSTGRES_DB=“ny_taxi” -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=“password” -v “${pwd}/ny_postgres_taxi_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data” -p 5432:5432 postgres:13
```

and then tried to connect through python using these commands

```
engine = create_engine(“postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/ny_taxi”)
db = engine.connect()
```

I need some help as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: From the docs: "Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.". If you have an existing database in `ny_postgres_taxi_data` you need to use the username/password already defined in the database.